# SwipeRefreshLayout com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, xml, swiperefreshlayout

I received this error:

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView android:id="@+id/news_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I have already restarted eclipse, but that not solve the error.

Comment: Please post logcat output.

Comment: @GauravArora It occurs in eclipse, not at runtime.

Comment: Works perfect for me, I am using  Luna Release (4.4.0). May be it's time for you to upgrade.

Comment: @GauravArora Can you please describe what do you mean "upgrade"?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this error by copy SwipeRefreshLayout from support library to my package.